# Stack Exchange API: How to get a suggested edit in Markdown?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, markdown, api

The API doesn't seem to provide `body_markdown` field for [suggested-edit](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit) objects. I wonder why. Is there any way to get an edit as Markdown?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably suspected, there is no such way via the API. The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) *does* contain the Markdown for suggested edits and may be used as a workaround: [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1376866) is an example.

[image]

The obvious downside is that SEDE is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday morning, so you'll miss recent suggested edits.